# remove excess grid div without content or center the bottom grid

Tags: html, css

i have grid container with 3 columns. However I only have 5 contents.

right now it looks like this:

```
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
|   4   |   5   |
```

I want to center the two remaining bottom div contents:

```
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
    |   4   |   5   |
```

Is this achievable or should I just create separate column for that?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's doable, but you'd be better of using `flex` instead here

Comment: Also this requires a 6 column grid.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do this easily.

1. You should create 2 variables for the amounts of columns and one for the gap. That going to make the rest easier to adjust and maintain later on.
2. Instead of grid use `display: flex`
3. To allow a break to the next row after a certain amount of elements you can use the `flex-wrap: wrap` property.
4. To center the child elements within that "grid" you can use `justify-content: center` which will center the elements along the main axis.
5. Now the hard part is to calculate the correct width of the grid cards. For that, you can use the `calc`-function. The entire width is `100%` from here we need to start. Then we need to subtract the gaps. The amount of gaps is `columns - 1`. Then we multiply the number of gaps by the gap size: `(amount of gaps - 1) * gap size`. That value we subtract as said from the 100% width: `100% - ((amount of gaps - 1) * gap size)`. Last but not least we divide that sum by the number of columns:

```css
:root {
  --grid-columns: 3;
  --grid-gap: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--grid-gap);
}

.container > * {
  width: calc((100% - (var(--grid-gap) * (var(--grid-columns) - 1))) / var(--grid-columns));
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with grid then what you have is a 6 column grid, each item taking up two columns and the 4th item starting at column 2 and the 5th item starting at column 4.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}

,
span:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 4 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```